# Не выводится список, думаю проблема в добавлении, в цикле while

Tags: c++

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
 int data;
 Node *next;
};
class List
{
private:
 Node  *head;
public:
 List()
 {
  head = NULL;
 }
 void push_list(int a)
 {
  Node  *uzel = new Node;
  uzel->data = a;
  uzel->next = NULL;

  if (head == NULL)
  {
   head = uzel;
   
  }
  else
  {
   Node *current = head;

   while (current->next!=NULL)
   {
    current = current->next;

    current->next = uzel;
   }
  }
 }
 void print()
 {
  Node *current = head;

  while (current!= NULL)
  {
   cout << current->data << endl;
   current = current->next;
  }
  
 }
 
};

int main()
{
 List name;

 name.push_list(6);
 name.push_list(7);
 name.push_list(8);
 name.print();
 
 
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно одну строку переставить в push_back

Было

```
while (current->next!=NULL)
{
    current = current->next;
    current->next = uzel;
}
```

Стало

```
while (current->next!=NULL)
{
    current = current->next;
}
current->next = uzel;
```

Comment: Спасибо, довольно, оказывается, глупый вопрос